# missing number or max number from the list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for missing number in the list, it works perfectly fine but when it start from 2, would it be possible to get 1. in below insertion
it should provide 1 not 4. please help thanks

```
drop table #temp
create table #temp
(
Number INT
)

insert into #temp
(Number)
select 2 union all
select 3 union all
select 5


SELECT MIN(t1.Number) + 1 AS MissingNumber 
FROM #temp t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp t2 ON (t1.Number + 1 = t2.Number) 
WHERE t2.Number IS NULL
```

Comment: what is the purpose of performing this operation?

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you to create a separate `numbers` table to do this.

There a many ways to create number table. Check this [link](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) for more info

```
SELECT TOP (1000) n = Row_number()OVER (ORDER BY number)
INTO   #numbers
FROM   [master]..spt_values
ORDER  BY n;

CREATE TABLE #temp
  (Number INT)

INSERT INTO #temp(Number)
SELECT 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 5

SELECT Min(t1.n) AS MissingNumber
FROM   #numbers t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp t2
                    ON ( t1.n = t2.Number )
WHERE  t2.Number IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible because join doesn't knows that number starts from 1. it will search for min value.

we can use while loop to solve problem

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #temp
CREATE TABLE #temp ( Number INT )
INSERT  INTO #temp
        ( Number )
VALUES  ( 2 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 5 );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   n = 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   n + 1
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    n <= 100 --can be increased with OPTION  ( MAXRECURSION {iteration value} ) at the end of the query
             )
    SELECT  MIN(cte.n) AS MissingNumber
    FROM    cte
            LEFT JOIN #temp t ON ( cte.n = t.Number )
    WHERE   t.Number IS NULL
```